# How to add a property to an existing class programmatically?

Tags: class, properties, t4, partial, codedom

I want to add another property `public int ID { get; set; }` to the class below using C#.
I don't know if there is a way beside T4 or partial class. How about CodeDom? I'm not familiar with it. Please do me a favor, Thanks!

```
public class DgItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: So you can't just modify the source code? CodeDom can output source code but it can't do anything that you wouldn't be able to do manually yourself.

Comment: I just want to append the second property. But, if have to, you can delete the class and recreate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a field for your property

```
CodeMemberField cmf = new CodeMemberField(new CodeTypeReference(type), name);
cmf.Attributes = attr;
cmf.InitExpression = new CodePrimitiveExpression(value);
```

You create your property

```
CodeMemberProperty cmp = new CodeMemberProperty()
   {
   Name = name,
   Type = new CodeTypeReference(type),
   Attributes = attr,
   };
```

Then add the get and set statements

```
cmp.GetStatements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), field.Name)));
cmp.SetStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), field.Name), new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()));
```

And that should do the trick

Comment: Sorry for reply so late! You are a great help! The code is a bit complicated. I learn a lot! Thank you!